# Queuing large number of celery tasks

Tags: python, celery

I'm writing a python3 app using Celery distributed task scheduling library.
Workers are using greenlet threads for processing. The task is I/O related with network operations.

I need to insert large number of celery tasks as single group. In this case it's around 10000 (10k) urls at once, each as seperate celery task.

Such insertion as single group, with redis or rabbitmq running on localhost is taking almost 12 seconds. Which is way too long.

**Q: Is there any way to optimize this bulk insertion using celery?**

In other threads i found people adivising use of chunks, however when i submit it in the chunks - the single chunk is being processed in single thread (not utilizing greenlets, which are necessary because of blocking IO on worker operations). That results in performance degradation. Consider following numbers:

1. No-chunks: Insertion 12 second, processing 9 seconds.
2. With chunks: Insertion 3 seconds, processing 27 seconds.

So using chunks is impossible as the blocking network operations are going to kill the performance benefit of greenlet threads.

```
soa = open('input.txt').readlines()
for line in soa:
    line = line.strip()
    s = line.split(':')
    l.append(check.s(s[0], s[1]))
    #l.append(s)
t = time.time()

res = check.chunks(l, 10)()
#print(res.get())
print("Submission taken %f" % (time.time() - t))

exit()
```

Chunks Result: Submission taken 2.251796 seconds

```
l = []

soa = open('input.txt').readlines()

for line in soa:
    line = line.strip()
    s = line.split(':')
    l.append(s)

job = group(l)
t = time.time()
result = job.apply_async()
print("Submission taken %f" % (time.time() - t))
```

Regular Result: Submission taken 12.54412 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Celery literally has a task wrapper called Group and Chunk.

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html

Chunk requires a results backend, I think, but just splitting your task into groups of say 50 to 200 URLs should allow Celery to optimize for you.

However if you are executing 10000 network-bound tasks, then it's going to take a hot second.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are answering with something i'm aware of, as initial post states. It mentions groups and chunks.Chunks won't work in this situation, due to fact that chunks kills network eventlet concurrency possiblities.

Comment: That's a fair question. However if you are sticking with Celery, there isn't really another option. I'm not sure how to profile in Celery but that might be a good google. Increasing your worker count to some large number might also work. Asyncio is also possibly better as each worker might be waiting for a response before firing the next request.